# include.gradle file being generated is causing problems

Tags: android, telerik, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

When building a project I get the following error:

> Flavor 'nativescript-telerik-ui' has unknown dimension 'nativescript-telerik-ui'.

It happens only when using the pro version through the @progress registry. Doesn't happen with the local .tgz pro version.

I noticed the error has to do with the include.gradle file it generates. I read the following article: https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins#includegradle-specification

It says that when the plugin doesn't have the include.gradle, at build time gradle creates a default one with default elements. When I saw the include.gradle it generated for the plugin it seems to have generated a default one like so:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        "nativescript-telerik-ui" {
            dimension "nativescript-telerik-ui"
        }
    }
}
```

The include.gradle generated for the local .tgz version of the plugin is like this:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        "F6" {
            dimension "nativescripttelerikuipro"
        }
    }
}
```

I replaced the default include.gradle with the latter and it got past the error. You can recreate the problem by following these steps:

1. create a new hello world app
2. use the command `npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress` to log in if you're a paying customer.
3. use the command `npm install --save @progress/nativescript-telerik-ui-pro` to install the plugin
4. use `tns run android`

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem? Really need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Vladimir and I am part of the nativescript-telerik-ui-pro team. Thank you for logging [this issue](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/191) in our feedback portal. We are going to review it as soon as possible and update you regarding its status, but from what I currently see there is some incorrect "parameters" passed to the 'pro' version of the plugin that are going to be resolved very fast.

We apologize for any inconvenience that this is causing.